# Calling functions within an object

Tags: javascript

I've created an object as follows.

```
function StartObj() {
   var events = {
      a: function() {
         alert("hello");
      },
      b = function() {
         lightbox(events.a);
      }
   };

   this.main = function() {
      $("#objId").click(events.b);
   }

}

$(document).ready(function(){
      var _start_obj = new StartObj();
      _start_obj.main();
   });
```

And in another file,

```
function lightbox(funcPtr) {
   alert(funcPtr);
}
```

The alert is reporting funcPtr is undefined; also the google chrome console.

Comment: How are you calling it? These are just definitions. (I think your issue might be with what `this` means inside your `b` function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't do what you think you do.

The line `var that = this;` is useless and `this`, anyway, isn't really x but the receiver of the `x.b` function.

This means that if you do

```
x.b();
```

this works

but if you do

```
var f = x.b;
f();
```

this doesn't work.

If you want to ensure that the working of `x.b` isn't dependent of the receiver of the function, you may do this :​

```
var x = function(){
    var x ={
       a: function() {
           alert("hello");
       } 
    };
    x.b = function() {
        mayhem(x.a);
    }
    return x;
}();
```

An alternative would be to create a constructor and make x using the `new` operator.

---

Regarding you edit :

If you want main to be accessible, do this :

```
function StartObj() {
   var events = {
      a: function() {
         alert("hello");
      }
   };

   events.b = function() {
         lightbox(events.a);
   };

   this.main = function() {
      $("#objId").click(events.b);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you plz review my question ?

Comment: See edit. But what do you want to alert ? the function code or just "hello" ?

Comment: Actually, the parameter I'm passing inside the function is a callback function which will be called when the lightbox initializes itself. I'm just checking with a function stub.

Comment: @dystroy: Your last code with the prototype doesn't work, because `events` is local to the constructor

Comment: @Bergi Right : too many copy-paste... As it's yet confused enough and probably not relevant I remove the prototype version...

Comment: Hey. This works. But whatz the logic behind this ? Why doesn't this work when I consolidate the functions inside the variable ?

Comment: I'm not sure of how you thought about that so my explication may not be clear but did you get what I said about this being the receiver of the function ? Calling x.b(); defines this as x but if you call the function x.b differently, this will be another object (often window when given as callback to an event manager).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure? this is works for me... I just added the call to `x.b()` to start it up

```
var x = {

a: function() {
   alert("hello");
},

b: function() {
       var that = this;
       mayhem(that.a);
    }

}

function mayhem(funcPtr)
{
   funcPtr();
}

x.b();
```

Comment: I'm not calling x.b straight away. I'm initializing an object and then I'm calling.

Answer (score 0):

You've screwed up your `StartObj` constructor - it does not return an object with a `main` method, `main` is just a local function. Also, you've got a closing brace too much after the assignment of `events.b`. This should work:

```
function StartObj() {
   var events = {
        a: function() {
            alert("hello");
        },
        b: function() {
            lightbox(events.a);
        }
    };

    this.main = function main() {
        $("#objId").click(events.b);
    }   
}
```

Also, make sure that `lightbox` is really globally available - check your error console.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply dude. I"ve put the closing bracket properly. But when pasting here, I made a mistake